# watermark template tag import error

Tags: linux, django

in one of my django project  i have used django watermark which is absolutely working fine in my local server.But after i deploy it in a Linux server , i am facing an error which is just like that...

```
'watermark' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading    watermarker.templatetags.watermark: No module named Image
```

i have installed all the dependencies and after facing this error i thought that it is occurring because of Pillow ,so thats why i have uninstall the Pillow and install it again in my virtual environment.But still i am facing this error.

this is my project directory...

```
medicalArt--------
          photo---
               views.py
               models.py
               __init__.py
               urls.py
               admin.py

          home----
              views.py
              models.py
              __init__.py

          templates----
              home-----
                  index.html
              photo----
                  showphoto.html

          watermark----
                  templatetags---
                          __init__.py
                            watermark.py
                  admin.py
                  models.py
                  __init__.py
                  utils.py
```

here is the full directory of my project.
Error is occurring in the **home/index.html** which is rendered from view of **home** app.you can find the **home** app in my project deirectory given above.The views.py of **home** app is given below....

```
# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from photo.models import Photo

def home(request):
    latest_images = Photo.objects.order_by('-uploaded_time')[:20]
    ctx = {'images':latest_images}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('home/index.html',ctx, context)
```

and the **home/index.html** is..

```
{% extends 'userena/base_userena.html' %}
{% load watermark %}
{%block content%}

<!-- carousel -->
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Medical Art</h1>
        </div>








 <!-- PORTFOLIO SECTION -->
 <div id="portfolio">


            <ul class="grid effect-2" id="grid">
                {% for image in images%}
                <li><img src={{image.photo.url|watermark:"Medical Art,tile=1,opacity=15"}}></li>
                {%endfor%}


            </ul>

  </div><!-- portfolio -->
  <br>
  </br>
  <!--About -->

  {%endblock%}
```

and this is the watermark.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from hashlib import sha1
import Image
import errno
import logging
import os
import traceback
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django import template
from watermarker import utils
from watermarker.models import Watermark

register = template.Library()

# determine the quality of the image after the watermark is applied
QUALITY = getattr(settings, 'WATERMARKING_QUALITY', 85)
OBSCURE = getattr(settings, 'WATERMARK_OBSCURE_ORIGINAL', True)
RANDOM_POS_ONCE = getattr(settings, 'WATERMARK_RANDOM_POSITION_ONCE', True)

log = logging.getLogger('watermarker')

class Watermarker(object):

    def __call__(self, url, name, position=None, opacity=0.5, tile=False,
             scale=1.0, greyscale=False, rotation=0, obscure=OBSCURE,
             quality=QUALITY, random_position_once=RANDOM_POS_ONCE):
    """
    Creates a watermarked copy of an image.

    * ``name``: This is the name of the Watermark object that you wish to
      apply to the image.
    * ``position``:  There are several options.

        * ``R``: random placement, which is the default behavior.
        * ``C``: center the watermark
        * ``XxY`` where ``X`` is either a specific pixel position on the
          x-axis or a percentage of the total width of the target image and
          ``Y`` is a specific pixel position on the y-axis of the image or
          a percentage of the total height of the target image.  These
          values represent the location of the top and left edges of the
          watermark.  If either ``X`` or ``Y`` is a percentage, you must
          use a percent sign.  This is not used if either one of the
          ``tiled`` or ``scale`` parameters are true.

          Examples:

            * ``50%x50%``: positions the watermark at the center of the
              image.
            * ``50%x100``: positions the watermark at the midpoint of the
              total width of the image and 100 pixels from the top of the
              image
            * ``100x50%``: positions the watermark at the midpoint of the
              total height of the image and 100 pixels from the left edge
              of the image
            * ``100x100``: positions the top-left corner of the watermark
              at 100 pixels from the top of the image and 100 pixels from
              the left edge of the image.

        * ``br``, ``bl``, ``tr``, ``tl`` where ``b`` means "bottom", ``t``
          means "top", ``l`` means "left", and ``r`` means "right".  This
          will position the watermark at the extreme edge of the original
          image with just enough room for the watermark to "fully show".
          This assumes the watermark is not as big as the original image.

    * ``opacity``: an integer from 0 to 100.  This value represents the
      transparency level of the watermark when it is applied.  A value of
      100 means the watermark is completely opaque while a value of 0 means
      the watermark will be invisible.
    * ``tile``: ``True`` or ``False`` to specify whether or not the
      watermark shall be tiled across the entire image.
    * ``scale``: a floating-point number above 0 to specify the scaling for
      the watermark.  If you want the watermark to be scaled to its maximum
      without falling off the edge of the target image, use ``F``.  By
      default, scale is set to ``1.0``, or 1:1 scaling, meaning the
      watermark will be placed on the target image at its original size.
    * ``greyscale``: ``True`` or ``False`` to specify whether or not the
      watermark should be converted to a greyscale image before applying it
      to the target image.  Default is ``False``.
    * ``rotation``: 0 to 359 to specify the number of degrees to rotate the
      watermark before applying it to the target image.  Alternatively, you
      may set ``rotation=R`` for a random rotation value.
    * ``obscure``: set to ``False`` if you wish to expose the original
      image's filename.  Defaults to ``True``.
    * ``quality``: the quality of the resulting watermarked image.  Default
      is 85.
    """

    # look for the specified watermark by name.  If it's not there, go no
    # further
    try:
        watermark = Watermark.objects.get(name=name, is_active=True)
    except Watermark.DoesNotExist:
        log.error('Watermark "%s" does not exist... Bailing out.' % name)
        return url

    # make sure URL is a string
    url = str(url)

    basedir = '%s/watermarked' % os.path.dirname(url)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(url))

    # open the target image file along with the watermark image
    target_path = self.get_url_path(url)
    target = Image.open(target_path)
    mark = Image.open(watermark.image.path)

    # determine the actual value that the parameters provided will render
    random_position = bool(position is None or str(position).lower() == 'r')
    scale = utils.determine_scale(scale, target, mark)
    rotation = utils.determine_rotation(rotation, mark)
    pos = utils.determine_position(position, target, mark)

    # see if we need to create only one randomly positioned watermarked
    # image
    if not random_position or \
        (not random_position_once and random_position):
        log.debug('Generating random position for watermark each time')
        position = pos
    else:
        log.debug('Random positioning watermark once')

    params = {
        'position':  position,
        'opacity':   opacity,
        'scale':     scale,
        'tile':      tile,
        'greyscale': greyscale,
        'rotation':  rotation,
        'base':      base,
        'ext':       ext,
        'quality':   quality,
        'watermark': watermark.id,
        'opacity_int': int(opacity * 100),
        'left':      pos[0],
        'top':       pos[1],
    }
    log.debug('Params: %s' % params)

    wm_name = self.watermark_name(mark, **params)
    wm_url = self.watermark_path(basedir, base, ext, wm_name, obscure)
    wm_path = self.get_url_path(wm_url)
    log.debug('Watermark name: %s; URL: %s; Path: %s' % (
        wm_name, wm_url, wm_path
    ))

    # see if the image already exists on the filesystem.  If it does, use
    # it.
    if os.access(wm_path, os.R_OK):
        # see if the Watermark object was modified since the file was
        # created
        modified = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(wm_path))

        # only return the old file if things appear to be the same
        if timezone.make_aware(modified, timezone.get_default_timezone()) >=   watermark.date_updated:

            log.info('Watermark exists and has not changed.  Bailing out.')
            return wm_url

    # make sure the position is in our params for the watermark
    params['position'] = pos

    self.create_watermark(target, mark, wm_path, **params)

    # send back the URL to the new, watermarked image
    return wm_url

    def get_url_path(self, url, root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        url_root=settings.MEDIA_URL):
    """Makes a filesystem path from the specified URL"""

    if url.startswith(url_root):
        url = url[len(url_root):] # strip media root url

    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, url))

    def watermark_name(self, mark, **kwargs):
    """Comes up with a good filename for the watermarked image"""

       params = [
           '%(base)s',
           'wm',
           'w%(watermark)i',
           'o%(opacity_int)i',
           'gs%(greyscale)i',
           'r%(rotation)i',
           '_p%(position)s',
           ]

    scale = kwargs.get('scale', None)
    if scale and scale != mark.size:
        params.append('_s%i' % (float(kwargs['scale'][0]) / mark.size[0] * 100))

    if kwargs.get('tile', None):
        params.append('_tiled')

    # make thumbnail filename
    name = '%s%s' % ('_'.join(params), kwargs['ext'])
    return name % kwargs

    def watermark_path(self, basedir, base, ext, wm_name, obscure=True):
    """Determines an appropriate watermark path"""

     hash = sha1(wm_name).hexdigest()

    # figure out where the watermark would be saved on the filesystem
     if obscure:
        log.debug('Obscuring original image name: %s => %s' % (wm_name, hash))
        new_file = os.path.join(basedir, hash + ext)
     else:
        log.debug('Not obscuring original image name.')
        new_file = os.path.join(basedir, hash, base + ext)

    # make sure the destination directory exists
     try:
        root = self.get_url_path(new_file)
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(root))
     except OSError, exc:
        if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            # not to worry, directory exists
            pass
        else:
            log.error('Error creating path: %s' % traceback.format_exc())
            raise
     else:
        log.debug('Created directory: %s' % root)

     return new_file

    def create_watermark(self, target, mark, path, quality=QUALITY, **kwargs):
    """Create the watermarked image on the filesystem"""

    im = utils.watermark(target, mark, **kwargs)
    im.save(path, quality=quality)

    return im

def watermark(url, args=''):
   """Returns the URL to a watermarked copy of the image specified."""

   # initialize some variables
   args = args.split(',')
   name = args.pop(0)
   opacity = 0.5
   tile = False
   scale = 1.0
   greyscale = False
   rotation = 0
   position = None
   obscure = OBSCURE
   quality = QUALITY
   random_position_once = RANDOM_POS_ONCE

   # iterate over all parameters to see what we need to do
   for arg in args:
       key, value = arg.split('=')
       key = key.strip()
       value = value.strip()
       if key == 'position':
        position = value
       elif key == 'opacity':
        opacity = utils._percent(value)
       elif key == 'tile':
        tile = bool(int(value))
       elif key == 'scale':
        scale = value
       elif key == 'greyscale':
        greyscale = bool(int(value))
       elif key == 'rotation':
        rotation = value
       elif key == 'obscure':
        obscure = bool(int(value))
       elif key == 'quality':
        quality = int(value)
       elif key == 'random_position_once':
        random_position_once = bool(int(value))

   mark = Watermarker()
   return mark(url, name, position, opacity, tile, scale, greyscale,
              rotation, obscure, quality, random_position_once)

 register.filter(watermark)
```

Comment: I suppose watermark is your custom tag. How do you load your custom tags in the template?

Comment: i load it directly such as {%load watermark%}

Comment: please provide the structure of your `templatetags` directory, as well as the content of your `watermark.py`

Comment: i have edited my post,please check it.

Comment: i have also provide the watermark.py file

Comment: well, as the error says, you are trying to `import Image`. What is `Image` and where is it located? Try to provide the absolute path for your import

Answer (score 1):

In `watermark.py`

replace

```
import Image
```

with

```
from PIL import Image
```

You may need to install pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```